# Получаю exception при вызове процедуры

Tags: java, procedure

Есть Процедура процедуру тестил она работает. Но когда в Java его вызываю получаю такой exception:

```
aa ERROR kz.test.app.session.MaketSession: error
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: Строка 1, столбец 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'ED_DATA'
ORA-06550: Строка 1, столбец 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Connection conn = em.unwrap(java.sql.Connection.class);
CallableStatement callableStatement = conn.prepareCall("{call x_h_p.ed_data(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )}");
callableStatement.setBigDecimal(1, id);
callableStatement.setString(2, gson.getDep());
callableStatement.setString(3, gson.getPayName());
callableStatement.setDate(4, stringToSqlDate(gson.getDateAppoint()));
callableStatement.setDate(5, stringToSqlDate(gson.getDateEnd()));
callableStatement.setString(6, gson.getSurchargeId());
callableStatement.setInt(7, gson.getExcludingSmd());
callableStatement.setDate(8, stringToSqlDate(gson.getBeginSalary()));
callableStatement.setDate(9, stringToSqlDate(gson.getEndSalary()));
callableStatement.setInt(10, gson.getBestSmz());
callableStatement.setFloat(11, gson.getDisability());
callableStatement.setFloat(12, gson.getBaikonur());
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(13, OracleTypes.FLOAT);
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(14, OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
callableStatement.execute();
```

14 параметров имеет процедура , но все верно передаю но получаю ошибку по аргументам

Comment: Может нумерация параметров должна идти с 0 по 13?

Comment: нет нумерация начинается с 1

Comment: может быть напутали с типами, тут засовываете к примеру float, а требуется int...и система не может скастовать float к int.

Comment: эх если бы так , но нет все типы совпадают

Comment: Подскажите, это не функция случаем? Ничего не должна возвращать? К примеру на оракле боролся вот так с функцией: `{call ? := doMe(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}`. Был ещё вариант `select doMe(?, ?, ?, ?, ?) from dual`

Comment: это процедура возвращает 13 и 14 один из них возвращает если тру то резальт если фолсе то мессадж